# Как мне подсоединить Slave MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, репликация

У меня есть продакшен база данных. Останавливать её нельзя. При всё этом кошмаре мне надо подсоединить Slave сервер с репликацией на него. Стандартные мануалы не подходят. Так как мастер сервер нельзя лочить на запись.